# jQuery Ajax url reference

Tags: jquery, .net

I am using jQuery ajax to call C# class named **A**'s WebMethod (a static method named **B**) . The aspx page named **C** (where the js script is referred) is in the same folder of **A**. And finally the js script **E** is in folder **D** which is the in the same folder of **A** as well.

In a word, A(file.cs), C(file.aspx), D(folder) is in the same location, while B(method) is within A and E(file.js) is within D.

I have trouble refer to the WebMethod.
From the ajax Url, I have tried:

url:"A/B" 
url:"/A/B" 
url:"../A/B"
url:"../../A/B"

none of them is working. Can anyone advise how to put the correct url? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your try here ?

Comment: I have tried 
url:"A/B" url:"/A/B" url:"../A/B" url:"../../A/B".
What is the standard way to call web method if the method is not in the cs code behind?

Comment: Post your code here. so that we can look in to and suggest what are you missing.

Comment: try this: `~/A/B`

Comment: Thanks @Aminur, but ~/A/B is not working..

Comment: can you provide the ajax call code here?